# Can't Connect to Heroku Postgres DB After Heroku Maintenance

Tags: php, postgresql, ssl, heroku, tls1.2

I've been using Heroku's Postgres databases for years now, and connecting from my MAMP localhost on Mac with no issue.

However, my databases have recently been upgraded by Heroku maintenance, and now when using MAMP localhost I am getting the following PHP PDO error:

"SQLSTATE[08006] [7] SSL error: tlsv1 alert protocol version"

From what I understand, this is because Heroku now requires TLS version 1.2 or higher to connect to Postgres. I have verified I am using TLS 1.3 locally, but I am still getting this error.

How can I locally connect to my remote Heroku Postgres database from my Mac running PHP?

I have been researching this issue extensively and have been unable to unblock myself.

Thanks in advance to anybody who can help.

Comment: Sounds like a question you should ask Heroku support?

Comment: @M.Eriksson I tried, they apparently don't help people debug their local dev environments.

Comment: Well, they did a change on their end (which we can't really know the extent of) that caused your app to stop working, so I still see it as a support case for them.

Comment: This was Heroku's response: "You mentioned you are running TLS 1.3 locally, however, it looks like this is being overwritten when you trying to connect, and the older version of TLS is used instead.
Without having the insight into local settings, we can't say where this is being overwritten, however, some settings to check are PHP PDO driver and MAMP."

Answer (score 0):

Solution I ended up going with for anyone else in this situation. I ended up updating the version of MAMP I was running on my Mac from MAMP 5 to MAMP 6, which included the proper versions of OpenSSL and libpq. I can once again connect to the updated remote Postgres database on Heroku. Thank you to user Ph00 Bar in the Postgres Slack group!